# How to compare date today with date present in an SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am executing a query where I am trying to compare the date in the database to the date today.

I am looking for the number of people that haven't left the company and for the ones where Exit Date is more than the current date.

What I am trying to do is as follows:

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM CompanySystemUsers 
WHERE [Exit Date] IS NULL OR *To add code here*
```

[Exit Date] has a datatype of date in the table CompanySystemUsers

In *To add code here*, I want to add the comparison statement where I can compare today's date to the [Exit Date] column values in the table

Comment: `[Exit Date] IS NULL OR >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)`

Comment: @TI Sql Exception: Incorrect syntax near '>'.

Comment: `[Exit Date] IS NULL OR [Exit Date] >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)`

Comment: Re-Tagged with `sql-server` based on the non-standard "quoting style" using `[..]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
select count(*) from CompanyStsystemUsers 
where [Exit Date] is null or [Exit date] >= cast(getdate() as date)
```

what you need is `getdate()`

Comment: the sql query cannot understand the > operator

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

### Cast([Exit Date] as date)> cast(getdate() as date)

Comment: [Exit Date] already has the datatype date, why are you casting it again?